# What is wrong with strpos()?

Tags: php, string, function

Have code:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/page-2.html';
if ($strpos = strpos('/page', $url)) echo '1';
else echo '2';
```

It shows only '2'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you read documentation?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the code? There is no comparison,in the if statement, only assignment. Also, we don't know what is the value of `$strpos`

Comment: Also, use === and !== etc with strpos. It is very important with strpos as mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change arguments places

```
strpos($url, '/page')
```

[strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Also `strpos` return `false` if needle not found. use `===`

Comment: Oh thanks. You have saved me a lot of time. Forgot arguments order.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the syntax for function was mismatched I think.
use this

```
    $stropos = stripos($url,"/page");
    echo $strpos;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add `===` identical compare in if condition and correct the position of `strpos` parameters

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/page-2.html';
if ($strpos == strpos($url, '/page')) echo '1';
else echo '2';
```